# Can I use setAttribute to set div's html value like $('#div').html("value");

Tags: jquery, html, setattribute

I can't use the basic $('#div').html("value"); to change the text of a div like I'm used to. Instead I'm trying to use div.setAttribute(...). Is there any way to set the "html" using it?

Sorry for the noob question, I haven't learned to manipulate my divs in this way yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a DOM element and not a jQuery object, you'd use `.innerHTML`.

```
div.innerHTML = 'new value';
```

If you need to append content, you could *technically* use:

```
div.innerHTML += 'new value';
```

but be very careful with that since it destroys the existing nested content and recreates it.

Better would be to create an element, append your content to that using `.innerHTML`, then append the children of the new element.

```
var temp_div = document.createElement('div');

temp_div.innerHTML = 'some new content';

while( temp_div.firstChild ) {
    div.appendChild( temp_div.firstChild );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't set a DIV's html content using setAttribute, as there is no html attribute on the DIV element. Why can't you use .html()?

You may also consider the following as an alternative:

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: New way we're setting up html/js functionality. I miss the simple way :(

Comment: Something isn't right about that. Even if you're doing something new, if you're using jQuery to edit the DOM, then the HTML within the DOM (DIV) element should be available to you.

Comment: If I was more familiar with it, I could explain it better to you. Bleh! But it turns out that the innerHTML works with the setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
div.innerHTML = "New text!";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_using.asp

You could also do `innerText`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the old-fashioned way, using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML):

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = 'mytext';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replicate the `html()` of jQuery, you can use `div.innerHTML`